# Calculate the total amount by levels

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The user has children, the children also have children, as in the example code. There are a maximum of 5 such levels, but maybe less, 2, 3. I'm trying to go through the levels and get the total amount of deposits of users of each level. The end result should be like this [300, 300, 300, 300]. But I seem to be doing something wrong. Help me please.

```
"children": [
                {
                    "id": "ddf86d60-a607-4a4e-a7f9-d96013ee7070",
                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                    "deposit": 100,
                    "bonus": 100,
                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "25de2e98-eb2d-41f4-b225-3069f942b284",
                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                            "deposit": 100,
                            "bonus": 100,
                            "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "376b202e-d44f-4402-9560-8498c855d05e",
                                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                                    "deposit": 100,
                                    "bonus": 100,
                                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "042681be-f521-40af-a1dd-a1591700f8e0",
                                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                                            "deposit": 100,
                                            "bonus": 100,
                                            "referralChildDeposit": 0
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "997e02a7-1bb7-473f-8ff8-5eb76d8d309b",
                                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                                            "deposit": 100,
                                            "bonus": 100,
                                            "referralChildDeposit": 0
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "b969c5b8-2d01-4872-8063-8e9ca7474a13",
                                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                                            "deposit": 100,
                                            "bonus": 100,
                                            "referralChildDeposit": 0
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "d8252898-46b8-4cf4-a545-06e98e6dccf1",
                                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                                    "deposit": 100,
                                    "bonus": 100,
                                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "0d6ae01b-ccda-4de3-83ca-d2f70dd0897c",
                                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                                    "deposit": 100,
                                    "bonus": 100,
                                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "0ee1ea8f-790f-4767-b280-c5cddfe9c630",
                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                            "deposit": 100,
                            "bonus": 100,
                            "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "eb530dbf-9026-4cb8-a3fa-d02133ced42d",
                            "name": "Rick Rich",
                            "deposit": 100,
                            "bonus": 100,
                            "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "d1022d3c-25af-461c-af91-cbc64147f92c",
                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                    "deposit": 100,
                    "bonus": 100,
                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "5927f160-e4ad-4b13-a47e-b1d4b0687897",
                    "name": "Rick Rich",
                    "deposit": 0,
                    "bonus": 100,
                    "referralChildDeposit": 0,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]


// My wrong code
const [userDeposit, setUserDeposit] = useState<number[]>([])

const iterateOfChildrenDeposit = (
        children: Children[],
        result: number[] = [],
    ): void => {
        children.forEach((node: Children) => {
            result.push(node.deposit)
            if (node.children) {
                iterateOfChildren(node.children, result)
            }
        })

        setUserDeposit(result)
    }

    console.log('userDeposit', userDeposit)
```

Comment: hey, can you remove the extra fields and keep the deposit field only which will make it smaller object, and how did we get the value 400 in the result?

Comment: I have reduced the input data. The array that I described as an example is purely an example. But I also changed it for better understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count array levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371547/count-array-levels)

Comment: Please don't make multiple questions for the same problem, all I had to change was `obj.children.length` to `obj.deposit` from your previous question and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample recursive function to get each level

```js
let child = [
    {
        "deposit": 100,
        "children": [
            {
                "deposit": 100,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "deposit": 100,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "deposit": 100,
                            },
                            {
                                "deposit": 100,
                            },
                            {
                                "deposit": 100,
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "deposit": 100,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "deposit": 100,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "deposit": 100,
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "deposit": 100,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {

        "deposit": 100,
        "children": []
    },
    {

        "deposit": 0,
        "children": []
    }
]
let res = [];
function iterateOfChildrenDeposit(children, result) {
    let tmp = [], d = 0;
    children.forEach((node) => {
        d += node.deposit;
        if (node.children)
            tmp = tmp.concat(node.children);
    });
    result.push(d);
    //console.log(result, tmp);
    if(tmp.length)
        return iterateOfChildrenDeposit(tmp, result);
    return;
}

iterateOfChildrenDeposit(child, res)
console.log(res);
```